# Matlab fminsearch using 'symfun'

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm using this code:

```
y1=symfun(c^2+p^2, [c,p]);
y2=matlabFunction(y1)
[x,fval]=fminsearch(y2, [0 0])
```

but it returns

> Error using makeFhandle/@(c,p)c.^2+p.^2
>   Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in fminsearch (line 191)
>   fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

How can I get around this?

Note that I'm using `symfun` rather than a function-handle, because I'm adding several functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend looking at the documentation for [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) and, in particular, the the [multi-dimensional examples](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html?refresh=true#zmw57dd0e237664) given. The `y2` function output from `matlabFunction` does not meet these requirements. You can change it by hand or you can try the [`'Vars'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#input_argument_namevalue_vars) option (as in [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html#zmw57dd0e80204)). You'll need to specify your initial guess as a column vector, but your example can be re-written as:

```
syms c p;
y1 = symfun(c^2+p^2, [c,p]);
y2 = matlabFunction(y1,'Vars',{[c;p]})
[x,fval] = fminsearch(y2, [0;0])
```

which of course returns the trivial solution `[0;0]` in this case.